# What is the required path in the key_data in Azure terraform script

Tags: azure, terraform, ssh-keys

I want to deploy a Linux machine in Azure using Terraform script but I am seeing in the ssh_keys that it is asking me to give the public key path.

But the public key path is in Azure Key Vault. How can I give the path here? Please assist.

Please refer to my code:

```
os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true

    ssh_keys = [{
      path     = "/home/default_user/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      key_data = 
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for is not currently supported by Azure. There is a feature request to add a Data Source to pull Secrets from Azure KeyVault, and the product team has been notified of that request. Please refer to the conversation below:

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/839

Comment: Thank you for your help